# What's the most effective way of running an IIS reverse proxy for a Hyper-V Ubuntu Machine

Tags: networking, iis, reverse-proxy, hyper-v, nextcloud

I've got Nextcloud set up in a Hyper-V machine, and IIS running a reverse proxy into the Hyper-V machine.  Right now, it's set up so that the reverse proxy rewrites the url using the IP address, but the issue is that the (internal) IP address of the Hyper-V machine keeps changing every time it reboots.

I've tried setting up a static ip within the Hyper-V machine but then the Hyper-V machine loses connectivity if I do, and I've tried rewriting the IP address using the hostname, but there's no DNS server so Windows can't resolve the hostname.

Is there any solution where I can set up the reverse proxy such that I don't need to keep editing the IP address of the rewrite every time I reboot?

Comment: dhcp reservation?

Comment: I can't find the dhcp reservation config in Hyper-V.  The Hyper-V instance is running on a different subnet (an internal subnet without only the host and instance) than the main network so dhcp reservation on the router doesn't do anything

Comment: "I've tried setting up a static ip within the Hyper-V machine but then the Hyper-V machine loses connectivity if I do" indicates you mess up the static IP settings. Did you set both static IP address/mask, as well as gateway IP address correctly? The last is often missed.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that when I reboot the machine, the IP of the host changes so I have to then go and reconfigure the default gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'm such a dingus.  It seems like the answer to this is to set a static *MAC Address*...

For anyone who sees this in the future: Using the default switch:
VM Settings -> Hardware -> Network Adapter -> Advanced Features -> MAC address -> Static